# Consumir WebService C# no android

Tags: java, android

Tenho um Web Service criado em C# onde acesso um determinado método para autenticar um professor, caso os dados de usuário e senha passado através de parâmetros exitem no banco o web service me retorna os seguintes dados [CodProf],[nome],[Usuário], [Senha].

Estou conseguindo passar esses parâmetros através de uma Activity de login perfeitamente e todos os dados estão sendo retornado.

O problema é que todo o código de acesso ao web service e de retorno desses dados está na classe da Activity.

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu estruturar minhas classes para ficar mais organizado.

Exemplo:

- Classe Professor: Onde vão conter todos os atributos e métodos get e set do professor.
- Classe ProfessorWs: Onde vai fazer receber os parâmetros da Activity e fazer a comunicação com o web service retornando um objeto do tipo professor.
- Classe da Activity responsável por capturar os dados digitados e passar para o ProfessorWs.

Código:

```
package feol.com.br.diarioescolar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Login extends Activity {


    private Button btEntrar;
    private EditText edUsuario, edSenha;

    private ProgressDialog dialogo;
    String codigo;
    String nome;
    String usuario ;
    String senha ;


    private static String SOAP_ACTION ="http://feol/AutenticarProfessor";
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://feol/";
    private static String METHOD_NAME= "AutenticarProfessor";
    private static String URL = "http://192.168.43.175/ServiceFeol.asmx?WSDL";


    Professor p = new Professor();
    ProfessorWs ws = new ProfessorWs();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        btEntrar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btEntrar);
        edUsuario = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edUsuario);
        edSenha = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edSenha);

        btEntrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btEntrarOnClick();

            }

        });


    }


    private void  btEntrarOnClick(){
        new asynProf().execute();

    }

    public Boolean invocaWs(){

        Boolean re = true;

        try{
             SoapObject resposta = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
             SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
             envelope.dotNet = true;
             resposta.addProperty("user",edUsuario.getText().toString());
             resposta.addProperty("senha",edSenha.getText().toString());
             envelope.setOutputSoapObject(resposta);


             HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
             http.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);

            String resultado = envelope.getResponse().toString();
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(resultado);


            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++ ) {
                JSONObject jsonObject =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                codigo = jsonObject.getString("CodProf");
                nome = jsonObject.getString("Nome");
                usuario = jsonObject.getString("Usuario");
                senha = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Senha").toString();
            }

        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            re=false;
        }catch (XmlPullParserException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            re=false;
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return re;

    }

    class asynProf extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){

            dialogo = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            dialogo.setMessage("Carregando codigo...");
            dialogo.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialogo.setCancelable(false);
            dialogo.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground (String... strings){
            if (invocaWs())
            {return "ok";

            }else {return "erro";}

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s){
            dialogo.dismiss();
            if(s.equals("ok")){
                mostraCod();
            }else {
                Log.e("Script","DeuErrado" + s.toString());}

        }
    }



    public void mostraCod(){
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Código pro: " +nome, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();

        }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Vamos lá, primeiro você precisa definir as responsabilidades do teu programa. Claramente essa activity tem muitas responsabilidades, então para estruturá-la melhor sugiro que você siga a seguinte arquitetura:

1. LoginActivity: Apenas inicializa os componentes da view e registra os listeners.
2. LoginOnClickListener: Trata o evento OnClick chamando os métodos que realizam a lógica de negócio através de uma fachada.
3. SOAPController: Fachada para os métodos de negócio que manipulam serviços SOAP.
4. GenericSOAP: Implementação abstrata ou interface de um SOAP que estabelece qual o formato das tuas classes SOAP.
5. LogonSOAP: Faz a chamada ao serviço de logon
6. UsuarioJSONObject: Converte dados JSONObject em usuários
7. Usuario: Encapsula os dados de um usuário: código, nome, usuário, e senha
8. AsyncTask: Implementa a chamada de tarefas assícronas. Lembrando que nomes de classes devem começar com a primeira letra maiúscula.^

Então, ficaria mais ou menos assim a divisão:

```
class LoginActivity {
    + onCreate
    + mostrarCod
    + carregarComponentes
    + carregarListeners
}

class LoginOnClickListener {
    + btEntrarOnClick
}

class SOAPController {
    + logar
}

interface GenericSOAP {
    + invocarWS
}

class LogonSOAP {
    + invocarWS
}

class UsuarioJSONObject {
    + converterJSONObjectParaUsuario
}

// É um POJO
class Usuario {
}

class AsyncTask {
    // Contrutor precisa receber a activity para iniciar a Dialog.
    // É importante iniciar a Dialog em uma thread separada (runOnUiThread).
    + AsyncTask (Activity activity)
    + onPreExecute
    + doInBackground
    + onPostExecute
}
```

Percebeu quantas responsabilidades tinha a sua activity? Quando você precisa usar um "e" para citá-las já é sinal de que elas precisam de refatoração. Sugiro que durante a refatoração você adote baby-steps, ir testando o código a cada passo e entendo o que está sendo feito por etapas.

Espero ter ajudado ^^